# How to start a ProgressBar if Firebase onComplete take longer then 3 sec

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, progress-bar

I want to make a call to Firebase and if it takes more then lets say 5 sec before
the `onComplete` surface I want to start a `ProgressBar`

Like this something:

```
// start some Thread here that will start `Progressbar`if 5 sec   
// passes before`onComplete` surface  

    Ref.updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
         // Turn of `Progressbar`           
        }
    }
```

How would I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a runnable and a handler on your class:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //show progress bar
    }
};
```

then setup the handler to run after 5 seconds:

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

Then on your onComplete method remove the callback to avoid the execution if the method last less than 5 secs.

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please mark it as the Correct Answer! thanks!